# Why do drivers get updated much more often than firmwares?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update, firmware, device-manager

Over the last few years, my computer's manufacturer has pushed updates for all of the following devices:

- HP BIOS
- Realtek HD Audio
- AMD HD Graphics
- Synaptics TouchPad
- Realtek Bluetooth
- Realtek WLAN
- Realtek Card Reader

The first was a firmware update, but all of the others were driver updates.
I've owned a few computers and it always seems that non-BIOS devices don't need firmware updates.

So, first let me confirm two things.
The non-BIOS devices in my list probably do each have their own individual private firmware, right?
If needed, these firmwares could be updated by the computer itself (with no special hardware/connection changes), right?

Then, why do devices tend to need driver updates much more often than firmware updates?
I suppose that this is by design due to fear of bricking the device (unlike a driver update, a mistaken firmware update might mess up the communication such that it can't get another update), so the device is designed with priority for flexible device-side operation from the start.

Comment: _"The non-BIOS devices in my list probably do each have their own individual private firmware, right?"_ - Not necessarily. Some of them could, but I'd expect for example Realtek HD Audio to be plain silicon IC. It can't afford the latency of a synchronous CPU, realtime processing is a must.

Answer (score 3):

> The first was a firmware update, but all of the others were driver updates. I've owned a few computers and it always seems that non-BIOS devices don't need firmware updates.

That's actually not *quite* true.

The BIOS one on your list is special because it is the only one that actually must store firmware in non-volatile memory. Because it needs to run before any operating system boots, any updates *must* be stored this way.

This is common only among those devices that need changes in pre-boot behaviour. Apart from your motherboard/BIOS, the only other ones are also involved in the boot process: storage and networking (if doing PXE boot). But in today's home environment those are usually integrated onto the motherboard and are part of the motherboard firmware package.

The other devices listed can have firmware. It's usually split into two parts:

- A non-volatile component, either hardcoded (in silicon) or very rarely updated. This is usually very basic or core functionality that almost never needs to change. All it needs to support is the most basic of pre-boot functionality plus the ability to load updated volatile firmware.
- A volatile component that is loaded by the host device (as part of the driver) every time. There is nothing to update here because their firmware, beyond a basic hard-coded package, is never persisted across reboots.

  The loading of this volatile firmware is usually silent, and you never notice it happening. There is no visible delay for a write to non-volatile memory, as you might have seen with BIOS updates. There is almost no risk, as a reboot brings everything back into a clean safe state.

Just picking two examples from your list:

- GPUs do have some level of firmware/microcode. In fact, they typically have what is known as a "VBIOS" with non-volatile firmware, almost never updated, along with volatile firmware that is always loaded by the OS. This historically caused quite some pain for Linux driver developers, as they must load binary firmware blobs to run the GPU. e.g. [Nouveau has had to jump through significant hoops to get those blobs from Nvidia](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/).
- WLAN cards also typically need volatile firmware loaded before they can run. This has, again, been an issue for Linux where they must load those binary blobs. e.g. [here are the firmware blobs for Intel WLAN cards](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#firmware).

Even your CPU has some level of "firmware", in what is known as the "microcode". This is never stored by the CPU, and on every reboot the CPU goes back to the same state as when you bought it. The BIOS (motherboard firmware) can load updated microcode into the CPU. The operating system can do the same. You'll see these as microcode packages on Linux, and they are shipped as part of chipset drivers or via Windows Update on Windows.

Comment: To clarify in different words, I think you are saying my WLAN card is probably getting some configuration ("volatile firmware") bits directly from the motherboard BIOS firmware every boot.
So, the "iwlwifi*.tgz" files in your link change the motherboard flash memory, not the wifi's personal flash memory?

Comment: @bobuhito Actually, those would be loaded by the driver in the OS. At some point during the OS's boot sequence, it will load those drivers and during the driver's load sequence it will load the firmware into the WLAN card. *In theory* your motherboard could do that too but (a) most motherboards don't support WLAN access during pre-boot stages anyway, and (b) the OS driver would likely need to reset the card on boot (I'm not sure how possible that is). The specific files I linked are used by the Linux drivers; while Windows ones are presumably similar, they're not quite so publicly available.

Comment: @bobuhito And there is no guarantee that the WLAN card even has any non-volatile memory at all (so no "flash memory"). It being volatile means it just gets loaded onto some form of RAM - often part of the microcontroller. The basic parts that enable the card to accept volatile firmware are often permanent parts of the hardware chip design (via mask ROM or similar, or just part of the circuits in silicon).

Comment: Why doesn't the CPU store microcode internally, so it can still access it in case the computer's main storage fails or the microcode is patching a bug which could render the CPU unable to read from the BIOS?

Comment: @Vikki Because (a) the as-shipped state is known good, and that means you always go back to a known good state on restart -- a good thing! it means there *can't* be a bug that prevents the CPU from having newer microcode installed (note: CPU isn't reading from something, other things are loading microcode into CPU), and (b) non-volatile storage both takes a lot of physical die space and is typically made using an entirely different silicon process than the logic on a CPU, so it would significantly complicate manufacturing.

Comment: @Vikki To expand further on (a), if the CPU had non-volatile storage and you loaded a corrupted set of microcode, or the storage got corrupted at some point after it were loaded, you now have a dead CPU. There's also no benefit: note that from an external perspective, the CPU + motherboard can be considered as one unit anyway, so the case where "the computer's main storage fails" to the extent that the motherboard/BIOS is inoperable, there's no point in the CPU otherwise working -- your machine as a whole isn't going to boot/run anyway.